# Ubuntu: trying to change username?

Tags: ubuntu

Before I started, I rebooted my machine and logged in as root.

And did, `usermod -l newname /home/newname -m oldname` to change my username.

Results in the error message

```
user oldname is currently used by process 4391
```

I tried `pkill -9 <processid>`, it kills it, but there are hundreds.

Tried `pkill -u oldname`, `sudo pkill -KILL -u oldname`, `sudo pkill -9 -u oldname`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm out of options, what else can I do to get around this?

Comment: Edit question to show output of `ps aux | grep oldname`.

Comment: You say you logged in as root. Then `sudo` is not necessary.

Comment: Please be specific about how you logged in as root

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you restart Ubuntu in recovery mode (from Grub menu), then choose 'drop to root prompt' and try it from there. I think it likely that it is some GUI activities that are causing all the active user processes.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root, then open terminal and run

> **kill -9 -u [old_username] && username -l [old_username] [new_username]**

After that run

> **adduser [new_username] sudo**

to be able to run sudo commands with the new username.